# Infographic conditional fill on custom SVG shapes

Tags: d3.js, svg

I want to create a kind of infographic where I can represent percentages intuitively using a kind of fill logic.

**Example**

For the sake of simplicity let's just assume intervals of 25%. For the task of 75% of households, there would be four houses in total and 3 of them would be filled in. The remaining house would remain `fill:'none'`.

I had something in mind like:

[image]

It would be in SVG form.

The only way I can think of to achieve this is pre-draw the houses as a collective image and link the file like:

```
var fileMap = { 50:'fifty.svg', 75:'seventy-five.svg'};
```

But this doesn't seem to be very modular, and it doesn't utilize `d3` hardly.

**Question:** Is it possible/feasible to create a simple 25% interval conditional fill using d3 compatible logic? What would my `.data()` call expect? It has to be an array, maybe a binary:

```
var data = [1,1,1,0] //75%;
```

Maybe there's a better way altogether, but that's the best I have got.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"I want to create a kind of infographic where I can represent percentages intuitively using a kind of fill logic"*... The technical name for this is **pictogram**.

For creating a pictogram you don't need anything special, you can use a common enter selection. So, given your data...

```
var data = [1,1,1,0]
```

... we will create one house for each array element...

```
var house = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
```

... and fill them according to the datum:

```
.style("fill", function(d){
    return d ? "blue" : "white"
})
```

Here is a basic demo:

```js
var d = "m787.67 1599.58l148.83 157.74 124.02-131.45v630.95h396.87 198.44 396.87v-630.95l124.02 131.45 148.83-157.74-768.94-814.97-768.94 814.97m1066.6-709.82v78.868l198.44 210.32v-289.18h-198.44z";

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var data = [1, 1, 1, 0];

var house = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", d)
  .attr("transform", function(_, i) {
    return "translate(" + (i * 70) + ",100) matrix(.04 0 0 .03-4.159-50.852)"
  })
  .style("stroke", "black")
  .style("stroke-width", "50px")
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return d ? "blue" : "white"
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Wow! That's awesome. Just wondering how I get the coordinates to make a path like in your `d` variable. If I'm not mistaken, I can open the svg in a text editor and just copy and paste for my `d` variable, right? Or do I have to go into adobe illustrator or other SVG program?

Comment: No need for Illustrator, you can open the SVG in the browser and just inspect the element.

Comment: I'm having a blast with this, it's such a cool technique. The only road-block I have been hitting was: `.attr('width', myWidth)` doesn't seem to change the size of the appended path. If I make the path smaller in Illustrator, it works fine, but is there no way to change the size from d3?

Comment: Please post it as a new question, with the relevant details. It's hard answering questions in the comments.